# Excell vba array loop inside another loop

Tags: excel, vba

I try to read cells from each row in excel and check if my cell contains value from my array.

```
Dim products As Variant
products = Array("MS-CHOPMAT-6", "MS-BOARDS-3", "MS-CHOP-LR")
Dim element As Variant

For x = 2 To LastRow

    order_quantity = Range("$E$" & x).Value
    item_price = Range("$F$" & x).Value

    For Each element In products

    If InStr(Range("$D$" & x), element) > 0 Then
             Range("$H$" & x) = order_quantity * 3

        Else: Range("$H$" & x) = "ERROR - " & order_quantity & element

        End If
    Next element     
Next
```

Unfortunately the "element" in the loop is always last array(products) element. In this case "MS-CHOP-LR".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a "nice trick" to find if a `String` is inside an array, it's by using the `Match` function.

For instance, let's say your cell String is "MS-BOARDS-3", then using the `Match` function will return a numeric value.

If your cell String is "MS-ELSE", then using the `Match` function will return an error , since it's not found in your array. So, if you add to that an `If IsError(Application.Match(Range("$D$" & x).Value, products, 0)) Then` you can trap this scenario, and directly pop-up your `MsgBox` you wanted.

**Code**

```
Dim products As Variant
Dim element As Variant

' add an integer variable for the "Match" function
Dim ArrElementID As Integer

products = Array("MS-CHOPMAT-6", "MS-BOARDS-3", "MS-CHOP-LR")

For x = 2 To LastRow

    order_quantity = Range("$E$" & x).Value
    item_price = Range("$F$" & x).Value

    ' if value not found inside the array using the "MATCH" function
    If IsError(Application.Match(Range("$D$" & x).Value, products, 0)) Then
        Range("$H$" & x).Value = "ERROR - " & order_quantity & element
    Else ' successful "MATCH" inside the array
        Range("$H$" & x).Value = order_quantity * 3
    End If

Next
```

Comment: hi Shai. How to find index of products in this code?

Comment: @awariat are you asking how to get the index of the `products` array ? using the `Match` function ?

Comment: No how to find index of products in this code you gave me. Which position was checked in if?

Comment: @awariat why do you need it ? you just wanted to check if it exist in the array of `products` and if it does to multiply `order_quantity` by 3, no ? In any case, if you mean when the `Match` was successful, you can get it with `Dim productInd as Variant` , and then inside the `Else` in my code above, use `productInd = Application.Match(Range("$D$" & x).Value, products, 0)`

Comment: I found: pos = Application.Match(Range("$D$" & x).Value, products, 0) is ok and pos is position in array

Comment: @awariat so your code works for you now as you intended ?

Comment: I need something more like two dimension array but having pos i created another array with two dimensions and is close to what I want

Comment: @awariat thanks for marking my answer and "ANSWER". If you encounter problems, open a new post, describe what you are trying to achieve, and upload your latest code attmept.

Answer (score 0):

1.
You can't use for each in an array. Use;

```
For i = LBound(products) to UBound(products)
... products(i) ...
Next i
```

Or make use of collections (google is your friend)

2.
The last line of your code should state

```
Next x
```

3.
LastRow might not always get you the right value. Use;

```
Cells(x,y).end(xlDown).row
```

If you know for sure you have a concatinae row, or

```
Cells(x,y).SpecialCells(xlLastCell).roW
```

To get the absolute last row in any range given from that cell. Note that in both cases if there aren't any values below that cell the very last row of the worksheet is returned (65k something for xls 2003 and 1M something for xlsx 2007+). There are other options to get the last row in a range but these two are my favorite ones.

4.
If else statement doesn't require double column (:) after else

Comment: 1.  Iterating through each element in a Variant array does work.  2. The `x` in `Next x` is **optional** (but useful for keeping track of which loop is being ended).  3. The OP's code does not show how the `LastRow` variable was set, so they may have used the code you gave, or the probably better code of `Cells(Rows.Count, y).End(xlUp).Row`  4. The colon (`:`) on an `Else` line that contains the else code is automatically generated.  (Syntactically, the `Else` should not have any code following it, so the IDE inserts the colon statement separator to split the line into two statements.)

Answer (score 0):

It took me a few hours, but I think I have finally worked out what you are saying your problem is ... after your code runs, every cell in column H has either the value of `order_quantity * 3` or it has a value of `ERROR - xxxMS-CHOP-LR"`.

This occurs because you are going through **every** element in `products`, even after you find a match on either the first or second element, so the "error" message is displayed whenever the final element does not equal the product in that row.

I suggest you change your code as follows:

```
Dim products As Variant
products = Array("MS-CHOPMAT-6", "MS-BOARDS-3", "MS-CHOP-LR")
Dim element As Variant
Dim matched As Boolean

For x = 2 To LastRow
    order_quantity = Range("$E$" & x).Value
    item_price = Range("$F$" & x).Value

    matched = False
    For Each element In products
        If InStr(Range("$D$" & x).Value, element) > 0 Then
            Range("$H$" & x).Value = order_quantity * 3
            matched = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next element
    If Not matched Then
        Range("$H$" & x) = "ERROR - " & Range("$D$" & x).Value & " - unknown product"
    End If
Next
```

If I have completely misunderstood your issue, please update the question to give more information.  (Perhaps add screen dumps of what the current code is producing and what you expect it to produce.)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your quick answers.
I will use Shai Redo solution:

```
Dim products As Variant
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
products = Array("MS-CHOPMAT-6", "MS-BOARDS-3", "MS-CHOP-LR")
'products = Array(Array("MS-CHOPMAT-6", 11), Array("MS-BOARDS-3", 12),   Array("MS-CHOP-LR", 13))
For x = LastRow To 1 Step -1

order_quantity = Range("$E$" & x).Value
item_price = Range("$F$" & x).Value

' if value not found inside the array using the "MATCH" function
If IsError(Application.Match(Range("$D$" & x).Value, products, 0)) Then
    Range("$H$" & x).Value = "ERROR - " & order_quantity
Else ' successful "MATCH" inside the array
    Range("$H$" & x).Value = order_quantity * 3 & LastRow
End If

Next
```

It is ok for my one report but in another I need array in array something like this

```
products = Array(Array("MS-CHOPMAT-6", 11), Array("MS-BOARDS-3", 12),   Array("MS-CHOP-LR", 13))
```

How to use such array in "match" where products are?
Regards

Comment: It would be better for future viewers of this post if you accepted @ShaiRado's answer and deleted this one. If you have a second question then you should make a new post. This post is all about using the `Match` function whereas your second question lends itself more to something like a `Collection`